# Weird lighting artifact in render

Tags: rendering, lighting

[image]

Tried turning up maximum bounces to 12, still there but less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try changing the Ray Visibility settings instead.  *(Although turning up the maximum bounces might be better in cases where you need these settings turned on)*  
The two settings that I turn off to help me get rid of these artifacts are Glossy and Transmission.

You would find these settings under *Your light source > Object > Cycles Settings*.

**With both settings on:**

[image: both glossy and transmission settings on]

**With transmission off:**
[image: transmission setting off, glossy setting on]

**With both transmission and glossy off:**

[image]

Hopefully this helps you! :D